# How to get JSON Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have code to get JSON Object but now I need to get a JSON Array.

```
JSONObject jData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject rates = jData.getJSONObject("page");
        JSONArray namesArray = rates.names();
        for (int i = 0; i < namesArray.length(); i++) {
            String currency = namesArray.getString(i);
            String rate = rates.getString(currency);
            stringBuilder.append(String.format("%s: %s\n", currency, rate));
        }
```

Comment: jsonbject.getJsonArray("key")

Comment: What library are you using for parsing json? Is the code you have shared in question not working? What error are you getting? Did you try reading any tutorial about the json parsing library you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
 java.lang.Object optionWraper = data.get(key);
            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
            if (optionWraper instanceof JSONArray) {
                jarray = (JSONArray) optionWraper;
             } else if (optionWraper instanceof JSONObject) {
              jarray.put((JSONObject) optionWraper);
             }
```

You can parse the input object in either case **JSONObject** or **JSONArray** and don't need to worry about the type in runtime  .